# Combining all dates, and data, within a month!

Tags: ireport

I am trying to combine all days of each month into a date.

My query as off now:

SELECT
     inventory_items.`acquired_at` AS Date_Acquired,
     products.`name` AS products_name,
     SUM(inventory_items.`primary_quantity`) AS inventory_items_primary_quantity
FROM
     `inventory_items` inventory_items INNER JOIN `customers` customers ON inventory_items.`source_id` = customers.`id`
     INNER JOIN `products` products ON inventory_items.`product_id` = products.`id`
GROUP BY
     MONTH(Date_Acquired),
     products_name
ORDER BY
     MONTH(Date_Acquired)

I have a general idea of what to do, but not really sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you and your Date_Acquired is an instance of sql Date type
you can gat day of months as pasting below code inside a textfield

```
(new SimpleDateFormat("d")).format(new java.util.Date())
```

which suppose to give you numbers like 1,2,3,...18,19...

Extra:

`(new SimpleDateFormat("M")).format(new java.util.Date())` for month

`(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy")).format(new java.util.Date())` for year

```
(new SimpleDateFormat("d")).format(new java.util.Date())+" - "
+(new SimpleDateFormat("M")).format(new java.util.Date()) for getting a value like 28 - 01
```

Answer (score 0):

What database? A typical SQL database result can only contain one data value per field.  So you will not be able to retrieve all the products.name values in one result grouped by the month.  If you retrieve all the results under a specified month you can aggregate them later on.

Comment: It is giving each item for each week, and not each month.  What do I need to change to get all of the week to total up?